# For loop doesn't work correctly when parsing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I met some problems with a for loop in my code.
It has to parse an array containing 3 objects, and move them if the conditions are right. But only the **first** object is detected and moved, the 2 others are never detected. I don't understand why, because I did other methods like that and I'd never have any problems.

This is the method and I know that's difficult to understand, but the problem is the fact that the 'box' object detected is always the first of the array, and never the second or the third.

```
Player.prototype.move = function(direction) {

  for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) {
    var box = boxArray[i];

    // Enregistrement de la position dans le tableau d'undo/redo
    this.index++;
    var array = [this.x, this.y, this.id];
    this.undoArray.push(array);
    // Définition de la direction de déplacement 
    if (direction == 'RIGHT') {
        this.moveCoeff = 1;
        this.moveLength = 1;
    }
    else if (direction == 'LEFT') {
        this.moveCoeff = -1;
        this.moveLength = 1;
    }
    else if (direction == 'TOP') {
        this.moveCoeff = -1;
        this.moveLength = 11;
    }
    else if (direction == 'BOTTOM') {
        this.moveCoeff = 1;
        this.moveLength = 11;
    }

    // Si box à côté et pas de collision possible 
    if ((controller.left || controller.right || controller.top || controller.bottom) && 
        box.id == this.id + (this.moveLength * this.moveCoeff) && 
        currentLevel[this.id + (this.moveLength * 2 * this.moveCoeff)] != 1 && 
        currentLevel[this.id + (this.moveLength * 2 * this.moveCoeff)] != 2) {
        // Décalage de la position du player 
        if (direction == 'RIGHT' || direction == 'LEFT') this.x += this.boxWidth * this.moveCoeff;
        else this.y += this.boxWidth * this.moveCoeff;
        this.id += this.moveLength * this.moveCoeff;
        currentLevel[this.id] = 8;
        currentLevel[this.id - (this.moveLength * this.moveCoeff)] = 0;
        // Décalage de la position de la box            
        if (direction == 'RIGHT' || direction == 'LEFT') box.x += this.boxWidth * this.moveCoeff; 
        else box.y += this.boxWidth * this.moveCoeff; 
        box.id += this.moveLength * this.moveCoeff;
        currentLevel[this.id + (this.moveLength * this.moveCoeff)] = 2;
    }
    // Sinon si aucun objet à côté 
    else if ((controller.left || controller.right || controller.top || controller.bottom) && 
        (currentLevel[this.id + (this.moveLength * this.moveCoeff)] == 0 || 
        currentLevel[this.id + (this.moveLength * this.moveCoeff)] == 3)) {
        // Décalage de la position du player
        if (direction == 'RIGHT' || direction == 'LEFT') this.x += this.boxWidth * this.moveCoeff;
        else this.y += this.boxWidth * this.moveCoeff;
        this.id += this.moveLength * this.moveCoeff;
        currentLevel[this.id] = 8;
        // Décalage de la position du sol
        currentLevel[this.id - (this.moveLength * this.moveCoeff)] = 0;
    }
    // Fin du déplacement
    controller.right = false; 
    controller.left = false; 
    controller.top = false; 
    controller.bottom = false; 
  }
}
```

Here is the part where I push objects in the array (in a loop) :

```
var box = new Box();
box.id = i;
boxArray.push(box);
```

Comment: I think nobody tried to answer your question because there are too many lines. Try to make it tiny. Focus on the problem. And try to make a reproduciton of the problem in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: how do you fill out `boxArray`? can you include that part too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of the `for` loop, you say:

```
controller.right = false; 
controller.left = false; 
controller.top = false; 
controller.bottom = false;
```

Yet both of your conditions begin with:

```
if ((controller.left || controller.right || controller.top || controller.bottom) &&
```

and

```
else if ((controller.left || controller.right || controller.top || controller.bottom) &&
```

Which, after the first time through the loop, will *never* be met, so no action will be taken.

Did you mean for all the `controller.XXX = false` assignments to happen *after* the loop?